# No such method in Jogamp

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, jogl

Inside jogamp.opengl.Debug, propertyAccess.addTrustedPrefix is called with the arguments string,class and it returns a "no such method error" because addTrustedPrefix only takes one argument, a string. Is there a jogamp jar that doesn't do this/any fixes for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about [that](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/master/src/jogl/classes/jogamp/opengl/Debug.java#L47). It's not a bug. What are you trying to do? Would you like to use different properties to do exactly the same thing? As long as you use the supported properties, it works as expected. Sorry to repeat that but most of JogAmp maintainers except me don't come here, it would be better if you contacted us on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org).

I'm almost sure that this line is written with a security concern in mind.